# Group multiple columns in a only alias

Tags: mysql, sql

I need the value 'table_index' and 'profit' in just an alias

My SQL code is :

```
SELECT 
receipt.*,     
customer.name, 
input_product.table_index AS table_index,      
input_service.table_index AS table_index,      
input_other.table_index AS table_index,
output_product.table_index AS table_index,     
output_service.table_index AS table_index,     
output_other.table_index AS table_index,
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM receipt_itens WHERE receipt_itens.receipt = receipt.id) AS total_iten,
(SELECT SUM(VALUE) FROM input_product WHERE input_product.id = receipt_itens.in_product)  AS profit,
(SELECT SUM(VALUE) FROM input_service WHERE input_service.id = receipt_itens.in_service)  AS profit,
(SELECT SUM(VALUE) FROM input_other WHERE input_other.id = receipt_itens.in_other)  AS profit,
(SELECT SUM(VALUE) FROM output_product WHERE output_product.id = receipt_itens.ou_product)  AS profit,
(SELECT SUM(VALUE) FROM output_service WHERE output_service.id = receipt_itens.ou_service)  AS profit,
(SELECT SUM(VALUE) FROM output_other WHERE output_other.id = receipt_itens.ou_other)  AS profit

FROM    receipt

LEFT JOIN       receipt_itens ON receipt.`id` = receipt_itens.`receipt`
LEFT JOIN       input_product ON receipt_itens.`in_product` = input_product.`id`
LEFT JOIN       input_service ON receipt_itens.`in_service` = input_service.`id`
LEFT JOIN       input_other ON receipt_itens.`in_other` = input_other.`id`
LEFT JOIN       output_product ON receipt_itens.`ou_product` = output_product.`id`
LEFT JOIN       output_service ON receipt_itens.`ou_service` = output_service.`id`
LEFT JOIN       output_other ON receipt_itens.`ou_other` = output_other.`id`
LEFT JOIN       customer ON customer.`id` = output_service.`customer` OR
output_service.`customer` OR output_product.`customer` OR
input_product.`customer` OR
input_service.`customer`

WHERE   (              
    receipt.id LIKE "%%" OR            
    customer.name LIKE "%%"    
)

ORDER BY created DESC
LIMIT   0, 10
```

result's with duplicate columns

[image]

I just need ignore the repeated columns that is worthless, I tried use the **GROUP BY**, but it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using "CASE" in select part of query. Like:

```
CASE
        WHEN input_product.table_index IS NOT NULL THEN input_product.table_index 
        WHEN input_service.table_index IS NOT NULL THEN input_service.table_index 
        ....
        ELSE NULL
    END AS table_index,
```

and same thing for profit.